# ¿Como deshabilitar botón desde la view?

Tags: android, android-studio, botón, onclick

Tengo un formulario con muchos botones, asi que para no tener muchos eventos onclick implemente **onClick**  de la vista llamándola con:

```
setOnClickListener(this)
```

desde cada botón.

Lo que que necesito es una vez en el evento onclick deshabilita el botón que se clickeo, he logrado solamente obtener el id del botón con **view.getId()**.

¿Alguna sugerencia o de camino a seguir?

Comment: Riu agrega tu layout y el código que realizaste para que sea más completa tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente obten su referencia y usa el método [**setEnabled()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)) el cual habilita o deshabilita el estado de la vista, para deshabilitar debes usar `false`:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Ejemplos:

```
Button boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.<id de boton>);
boton.setEnabled(false);
```

o también usando su id:

```
Button boton = (Button)findViewById(view.getId());
boton.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funciono a la perfección, muchas gracias por el aporte. @jorgesys

Answer (score 1):

Si tenes el ID del boton podrias perfectamente

```
Button btn = find...(view.getId())

button.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Bruno, de igual manera es correcta tu respuesta, te lo agradezco.

Comment: Siempre es buena actitud votar positivo sin necesidad de darle a la paloma @Riu